# Is binding a property directly to a signal equivalent to subscribing to that signal and then setting the property?

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

Instead of writing this in my view controller:

```
@weakify(self);
[[self.view.emailAddressField.rac_textSignal distinctUntilChanged] subscribeNext:^(NSString *emailAddress) {
    @strongify(self);
    self.viewModel.emailAddress = emailAddress;
}];
```

What are the consequences and implications of using the following instead?

```
RAC(self.viewModel, emailAddress) = [self.view.emailAddressField.rac_textSignal distinctUntilChanged];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent, assuming `self.viewModel` has already been set by the time it is called.

Answer (score 3):

Just read the source code.

```
RAC(target, keyPath, nilValue) = signal;
```

is something like:

```
[signal setkeyPath:keyPath onObject:target nilValue:niValue];
```

and  `setKeyPath:onObject:nilValue:` is implementation as:

```
RACDisposable *subscriptionDisposable = [self subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSObject *object = (__bridge id)objectPtr;
    [object setValue:x ?: nilValue forKeyPath:keyPath];
} error:^(NSError *error) {
    ...
} completed:^{
    ...
}];
```